# What does "SELECT 1 + 1" :: IO [Only Int] mean in Haskell? (postgresql example)

Tags: postgresql, haskell

This is a very simple protgresql haskell example:

```
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple

localPG :: ConnectInfo
localPG = defaultConnectInfo
        { connectHost = "db"
        , connectDatabase = "clients"
        , connectUser = "docker"
        , connectPassword = "docker"
        }

main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connect localPG
  mapM_ print =<< (query_ conn "SELECT 1 + 1" :: IO [Only Int])
```

`conn` has type `Connection`, but what about `"SELECT 1 + 1" :: IO [Only Int]`? What is `:: IO [Only Int]`? I could not find about this on google. I guess it should resolve to `Query` somehow.

Here's `query_`:

```
query_ :: Connection -> Query -> IO [r]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::` denotes a [type signature](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_signature) (usually read "has type").  The type is `IO [Only Int]` and it applies to the entire expression in parens, `query_ conn "SELECT 1 + 1"`.

This tells the compiler that you expect `query_ conn "SELECT 1 + 1"` to be an IO action that returns a list of `Only Int`.  You will need to refer to the PostgreSQL to find out what `Only` means.

It is there because both `query_` and `print` have polymorphic types and without some help the compiler will not know what type to expect.

In any more then the simplest examples the type of the query will likely be inferred from the surrounding context, but since all this does is run a simple query and immediately print the results there needs to be some extra type information to get it to compile.  It can be instructive to remove the type signature and see what kind of error Haskell gives you so you know what it means when you see that error in your own code.